# Apps that include a custom keyboard extension must have a privacy policy URL

Tags: ios, app-store, custom-keyboard

I recently uploaded an app to the app store and it got rejected. The reason for the rejection was.

> "Apps that include a custom keyboard extension must have a privacy policy URL for [English]. If your app doesn’t provide a custom keyboard, remove the custom keyboard extension from your app and upload a new binary."

[App Store replay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIziC.png)

Comment: Isn't the error message rather clear about what you need to do? So, what is your question actually?

Comment: My question is simple, How to fixed this issue. I need privacy policy URL inside the app or provide a link in description while uploading to the app store.

Answer (score 6):

It should be enough to add the Privacy Policy to the URL field in iTunes Connect and link directly to your website where it's hosted. I couldn't find anything in the documentation that said it must be within the app.

[image]

Description of the pop-up:

> A URL that links to your organization's privacy policy. Privacy policies are required for apps that are Made for Kids or offer automatically renewable In-App Purchases or free subscriptions. They are also required for apps with account registration, apps that access a user’s existing account, or as otherwise required by law. Privacy policies are recommended for apps that collect user- or device-related data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are upload your custom-keyboard on App store then you have to put a  `privacy policy URL` mean you have to add one popup on your keyboard Application main page like following:

[image]

So you just create on local `html` page and upload on your hosting server. And on click the privacy Policy open new `View-controller` and load the privacy URL on `UIWebview`. that contain some rules and Team of use this custom Keyboard.

**Privacy-Policy Demo Contain:**

> Privacy Policy - Thumb KeyBoard
>
> Your privacy is a great concern to us. Read below to see what information is collected when you use Thumb keyboard iOS app, why it is collected, and how it is used to improve your overall experience when using the App.
>
> Collection of Personal Information
>
> We DO NOT COLLECT ANY INFORMATION THAT YOU TYPE using this app. When you allow full access for Thumb keyboard, you may be warned that the keyboard can be used to “transmit anything you type, including things you have previously typed with this keyboard.” This is the standard warning message for all third-party input methods, however Thumb Keyboard does not collect any personal information or transmit such information to a server or third party.
>
> Disclosure of Personal Information
>
> As we do not collect any personal information, your personal information is safe will not be disclosed to any third party unless you have consented explicitly to such a disclosure, or where there is a legal requirement for this to happen.
>
> Access Required and Usage
>
> Some of the features (including theme switching) of Thumb keyboard needs you to enable “allow full access.” The App need this access in order to read theme and setting information from the Thumb settings app. Thumb will only read data, and no personal information will be stored.
>
> Policy Changes
>
> Any changes to this policy will be posted to an update of the App. You are advised to regularly view our most recent privacy policy.

You can change the text based on your keyboard feature.

Comment: Thank you really appreciated, One more thing is this necessary to include privacy policy URL in inside the app, Or just providing privacy policy URL to app store.

Comment: i think that's the necessary to add url as i said in answer.

Comment: Thank you I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: @NitinGohel This doesn't work for me as I have PRIVACY POLICY link in app & I have posted link on app info page as well

Comment: As in my app i used above thing to fix this and my app live

Answer (score 2):

If you see the warning message at TestFlight popup, provide your Privacy Policy URL here.

[image: Privacy Policy URL]

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error.

You do not need to add anything inside the app, just on the test flights page as described in oOEric's answer.

I tried to fake it by using www.myurl.com but it kept rejected it.

As soon as I took the time to put www.myurl.com/privacypolicy.htm, that actually exists, it worked.

Looks like it goes and checks if you're privacy policy is legit, there is a slight load when you submit.